# Fluent NHibernate adding Where() in mapping constructor doesn't work with subquery

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have this entity mapping:

```
public class ExpedienteNnaMap : ClassMap<ExpedienteNna>
    {
        public ExpedienteNnaMap()
        {
            Table("personasexpediente");
            Id(x => x.Id, "gidexpediente");
            Map(x => x.FechaCreacion, "fecha");
            References(x => x.DetalleNna, "gidpersona").Not.LazyLoad();
            HasOne(x => x.CondicionMedica).ForeignKey("numero_expediente").Not.LazyLoad();
            Where("expnna = 'nna' AND gidexpediente in (select numero_instrumento from seguimiento s where idcustodio = '23')");
        }
    }
```

When I try to run my get all query Fluent NHibernate generates the following SQL statement:

```
select
    expediente0_.gidexpediente as gidexpediente1_9_,
    expediente0_.fecha as fecha2_9_,
    expediente0_.gidpersona as gidpersona3_9_
from
    personasexpediente expediente0_
where
( 
    expediente0_.expnna = 'nna'
    and expediente0_.gidexpediente in 
    (
        select
            expediente0_.numero_instrumento
        from
            seguimiento s
        where
            expediente0_.idcustodio = '23'
    )
)
```

I just need NHibernate avoid using aliases in subquery

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: have you tried `Where("expnna = 'nna' AND gidexpediente in (select s.numero_instrumento from seguimiento s where s.idcustodio = '23')");`?

Answer (score 0):

Set the alias of the subquery. When there is no alias set NHibernate will assume it is a column of the mapped table and assign its alias

```
Where("expnna = 'nna' AND gidexpediente in (select s.numero_instrumento from seguimiento s where s.idcustodio = '23')");
```